# Periodic Calendar value shifting after mid year

Tags: control-m

so I have defined a periodic calendar with following periods,

1. Period **A**: to factor in start of every month
2. Period **B**: to factor in end of every month

**Calendar**

[image]

Now I am trying to schedule the job on every days marked as period A i.e. start of every month by doing the following settings,

**Scheduling Setting**

[image]

**Schedule**

[image]

**My Problem**

From July month the schedule is getting pre-shifted by 1. Any ideas why?

Also can someone guide me to a detailed documentation on periodic calendars and the values example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to reproduce the specific issue you are having. I created the same periodic calendar (Per A = SoM, Per B = EoM) and my job schedule came out as expected.

**Calendar**

[image: Periodic Calendar]

**Job**

[image: Job Settings]
**Schedule**

[image: Schedule]

**Solution**

There is no need to use a periodic calendar for such a simple scheduling requirement. Making use of a periodic calendar incurs maintenance overhead as you need to ensure it is updated every year.
Instead of using a periodic calendar you could simply configure the job as below. This will result in a job that will always execute on the first day of each month, no maintenance required.

[image: New Job Definition]

Comment: Hi, this exercise was more for understanding the behaviour of periodic calendars and the shifts were confusing. Are there any parameters which could cause this shifts? Can you point to detailed documentation about the periodic calendar. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Is the job that you are testing with defined to run in a specific timezone that has DST? This could potentially change the job to order in a day in advance. The best documentation on periodic calendars is BMC's own Control-M Workload Automation User Guide. Unfortunately it is not very detailed and therefore searching around in BMC's knowledge base and other online communities may be necessary.

Comment: Ah, this could be the reason.